# materialize Circular Preloader nest more circle inside each other

Tags: html, css, materialize

i'm new using matriliazeCSS framework ,now i'm trying to achieve custom preloader by nest 3 circle inside each other rotating in the same direction.
my code :

```
    <div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
    <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
      <div class="circle-clipper left">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="gap-patch">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="preloader-wrapper active">
    <div class="spinner-layer spinner-red-only">
      <div class="circle-clipper left">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="gap-patch">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="preloader-wrapper small active">
    <div class="spinner-layer spinner-green-only">
      <div class="circle-clipper left">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="gap-patch">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this code display 3 circular preloader beside each other
any ideas about put them inside each other?!